# conditionally contain arguments in url path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a search function which allows a user to search for items. From the generated list, the user can add items to a list. After adding an item from the list, the page reloads and the user is returned to their current search list. However, currently, if a user has not searched for anything, and just adds an item of the top of the list (starting at 'A, for example), when the page reloads it includes a blank search query in the url. I know why, it is because of this line

```
redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job, search_term: params[:search_term])
```

I want to make the last argument in the redirect path a conditional one so that, if say the `:search_term == nil || == "" || " "` then the redirect_to only includes the first argument.

How would I best achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
if params[:search_term].present?
  redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job, search_term: params[:search_term])
else
  redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job)  
end
```

Or

```
redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job, search_term: params[:search_term].presence)
```

---

References:

- `.present?` [method documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)
- `.blank?` [method documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

Comment: The 2nd example doesn't work properly.  Please update your answer to match the other user's answer `redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job, search_term: params[:search_term].present? ? params[:search_term] : nil)`

Answer (score 1):

The second example of MrYoshiji probably will not work, but you can write it short and simple this why:

```
redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job, search_term: params[:search_term].present? ? params[:search_term] : nil)
```

So if the result will be `nil` rails will not include that param in the url